# Write new data into javascript variable and parse JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code which help me to show Verite Timeline on my page so:

```
<div id="timeline-embed"></div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        var timeline_config = {
         width: "100%",
         height: "100%",
         debug: true,
         rows: 2,
         source: {
    "timeline":
    {
        "headline":"Sh*t People Say",
        "type":"default",
        "text":"People say stuff",
        "startDate":"10/4/2011 15:02:00",
        "date": [
            {
                "startDate":"10/4/2011 15:10:00",
                "endDate":"10/4/2011 15:55:00",
                "headline":"FIRST",
                "text":"<p>FIRSTTEXT</p>",
                "asset":
                {

                    "caption":"yessss"
                }
            },
            {
                "startDate":"10/4/2011 17:02:00",
                "endDate":"10/4/2011 18:02:00",
                "headline":"SECOND",
                "text":"<p>In true political fashion, his character rattles off common jargon heard from people running for office.</p>",
                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"http://youtu.be/u4XpeU9erbg",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

        }
      </script>
```

so Now on `source:` into `date` I want to add new element:

```
{
                "startDate":"CurrentDate + zajson",
                "endDate":"10/4/2011 18:02:00",
                "headline":"place.name",

                "asset":
                {
                    "media":"http://youtu.be/u4XpeU9erbg",
                    "credit":"",
                    "caption":""
                }
            }
```

so offcource I have a variable:

```
var place.name;
var zajson;
```

and When I click on `<button>Add to timeline</button>` I want to add new element (as i show above) into source: in date, as new block of values ...

Is it posible to do this?

And how I can update source: and run it again when I add new block of data???

*sorry for my english*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addContent() {
    var content = {
        "startDate":"CurrentDate + zajson", // <-- these two probably shouldn't be in quotes, but concated
        "endDate":"10/4/2011 18:02:00",
        "headline":"place.name", // <-- this one, too
        "asset":
            {
                "media":"http://youtu.be/u4XpeU9erbg",
                "credit":"",
                "caption":""
            }
    };

    timeline_config.source.timeline.date.push(content);
}
```

Something like this should do it.

Then, for the button:

```
<button onclick="addContent()">Add to timeline</button>
```

Comment: and how I can update this to work inside my code without refreshing the page

Comment: but how when I click on button to call this last line code function ?

Comment: you can just add an onclick event to the button, or even better, make a function, I've updated my answer

Comment: I try: '<button'+onclick=timeline_config.source.timeline.date.push(new)+'>Add to timeline</button></div>'; but dont work... but I will fix it thanks very much...

Comment: The syntax in that is slightly bad... See my answer for a neater solution. You can also expand the addContent function to receive arguments and thus make it more flexible.

Comment: dont work probbaly becouse I must call button action ike this;             contentStr += '<button onclick="addContent()">Add to timeline</button>';

Comment: and after that I call contentStr in jquery dialog();